# Including a footer in WebsiteBaker

Tags: php, include, websitebaker

I'm trying to plan the implementation of a WebsiteBaker and have a footer with latest news information which is just updated manually by staff.

I was going to use a "News" block and add it to every page but then I have to update all pages when a new update is made.

Then I thought I'd leave it in the template but I don't want staff accessing the index.php via FTP to update the news... The same goes when I thought of just using an include but the staff would still need to be using FTP to make changes....

Does anyone with some WebsiteBaker knowledge know how I can create a block of content in the backend and include it at the base of every page?  Kind of like an attribute in Wordpress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about Section Picker:
http://addons.websitebaker.org/pages/en/browse-add-ons.php?id=04A1753

> The section picker (a.k.a. Global Blocks) allows you to re-use the
>   content from sections used in other pages.
>
> Any type of content can be re-used multiple times using this module. 
>   You could use it to build a library of content on a single hidden page
>   and build your public pages by just combining sections from your
>   library.
>
> Ideal to setup a content system for multiple admins/editors.

Answer (score 0):

Separate footer as a php page and include your footer page on your other pages.
Call news update functions on you footer page.

Comment: doesn't really help - someone still needs to ftp to the footer page.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hidden news page with a blank template.  Then curl the page into the footer.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using global blocks - I can create a block of hidden code on a page and access it from every other page.